# Uploading image to server does not work when .jpeg is the type

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using this script to upload images in .jpg & .png type to the server and database but when it comes to .jpeg or .JPG it does not work, instead of placing the file in right directory with correct extension it just does this /galleri/uploads/a4b7c7fb0de9c561110c2279f24ec820jpeg.php it automaticly adds .php on the end.

What I've been trying to do is to add these lines

```
if ( $type == 'image/jpeg' ) { $filetype = '.jpeg'; } else {  $filetype = str_replace( 'image/', '', $type ); }

if ( $type == 'image/jpeg' ) { $filetype = '.JPG'; } else {  $filetype = str_replace( 'image/', '', $type ); }
```

but with no use..

Aside from that is there any better crop tool I can use in this case that ain't so advanced?

This is the complete script:

```
if(isset($_POST['addmedia'])) {
    $mediatype =    escape(striptags($_POST['mediatype']));
    $title =        escape(striptags($_POST['title']));
    $video =        escape(striptags($_POST['medialink']));
    $date =         date('Y-m-d');

    if ($mediatype === 'img') {
        if( !isset( $_POST['p'] ) ) { $_POST['p']= 0; }

        if( $_POST['p'] == 1 ) {
            $name =     $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $temp =     $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $type =     $_FILES['image']['type'];
            $size =     $_FILES['image']['size'];

            if ( $type == 'image/jpeg' ) { $filetype = '.jpg'; } else {  $filetype = str_replace( 'image/', '', $type ); }
            if ( $type == 'image/png' ) { $filetype = '.png'; } else {  $filetype = str_replace( 'image/', '', $type ); }

            $path =             md5( rand(0, 1000) . rand(0, 1000) . rand(0, 1000) . rand(0, 1000) ) . $filetype;
            $thumb_path =       md5( rand(0, 1000) . rand(0, 1000) . rand(0, 1000) . rand(0, 1000) ) . $filetype;

            $size2  =   getimagesize ($temp);
            $width  =   $size2[0];
            $height =   $size2[1];

            $maxwidth   =   1281;
            $maxheight  =   751;
            $allowed    =   array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');

            if( in_array( $type, $allowed ) ) {
                if( $width < $maxwidth && $height < $maxheight) {
                    if( $size < 10485760) {
                        if( $width == $height ) { $case = 1;}   // Square form
                        if( $width > $height ) { $case = 2;}    // Lying form
                        if( $width < $height ) { $case = 3;}    // Standing form

                        switch($case) {
                            case 1:
                            $newwidth   =    280;
                            $newheight  =    150;
                            break;

                            case 2:
                            $newheight  =   150;
                            $ratio      =   $newheight / $height;
                            $newwidth   =   round($width * $ratio);
                            break;

                            case 3:
                            $newwidth   =   280;
                            $ratio      =   $newwidth / $width;
                            $newheight  =   round($height * $ratio);
                            break;
                        }

                        switch($type) {
                            case 'image/jpeg':
                            $img    =   imagecreatefromjpeg( $temp );
                            $thumb  =   imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
                            imagecopyresized( $thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
                            imagejpeg( $thumb, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/galleri/uploads/thumbs/" . $thumb_path );
                            break;

                            case 'image/png':
                            $img    =    imagecreatefrompng( $temp );
                            $thumb  =    imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
                            imagecopyresized( $thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
                            imagepng( $thumb, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/galleri/uploads/thumbs/" . $thumb_path );
                            break;
                        }

                        move_uploaded_file( $temp, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/galleri/uploads/" . $path );
                        $addimg = "INSERT INTO uploads (`type`, `title`, `src`, `thumb`, `date`) VALUES ('$mediatype', '$title', '$path', '$thumb_path', '$date')";
                        if ($add_img = $db_connect->query($addimg)) {}
                        echo 'Din bild har laddats upp!';
                        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

                    } else {
                        echo '10MB';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'To big in size';
                }
            } else {
                echo '.jpg, .jpeg, .png!';
            }
        }
    } else if ($mediatype === 'vid') {
        $name       =     $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $temp       =     $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $size       =     $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $thumb_path =     md5( rand(0, 1000) . rand(0, 1000) . rand(0, 1000) . rand(0, 1000) ) . '.jpg';

        move_uploaded_file( $temp, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/galleri/uploads/thumbs/" . $thumb_path );
        $addvid = "INSERT INTO uploads (`type`, `title`, `thumb`, `videolink`, `date`) VALUES ('$mediatype', '$title', '$thumb_path', '$video', '$date')";

        if ($add_vid = $db_connect->query($addvid)) {}
        echo 'Video uploaded';
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you do an `echo $type;` for your images which were not accepted and tell us the result ?

Comment: @akmozo I've noticed one thing when I removed the .png format the .jpg and the .JPG worked correctly.. this is weird

Comment: This is because your wrong conditions. I put an answer, take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php

    ...

    $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $size = $_FILES['image']['size'];

    $type = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($temp)); // get the real image mime type

    if ( $type == 'image/jpeg' ) { // jpeg

        $filetype = '.jpg'; 

    } else if ( $type == 'image/png' ){ // png

        $filetype = '.png';

    } else { // other image type

        $filetype = '.' . str_replace( 'image/', '', $type ); // to get .gif for a gif image, for example

    }

    ...

?>
```

Comment: Thanks it works awesome, however when I upload ex. a .gif it uploads it as .jpg and instead there should be a message that says that this type is not uploadable

Comment: Do you want to disable .gif upload ?

Comment: No, but I would like ot disable all others like .tga or .pdf etc

Comment: All is fine for you ?

Comment: Yes thanks! you're awesome! :) Now I have to figure out better way to crop thumbs :)